# Single duplicate in a vector

Tags: clojure

Given a list of integers from 1 do 10 with size of 5, how do I check if there are only 2 same integers in the list?

For example

```
(check '(2 2 4 5 7))
```

yields yes, while

```
(check '(2 1 4 4 4))
```

or

```
(check '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

yields no

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I can't get the logic behind this, I really can't

Comment: What about case like `(check '(1 1 2 2 3))`?

Comment: Thats false aswell, only one pair is needed

Comment: `frequencies` could help with this https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/frequencies

Comment: I've quoted your lists. As they were, they are failing function evaluations.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using frequencies to count occurrences and filter to count the number of values that occur only twice:

```
(defn only-one-pair? [coll]
  (->> coll
       frequencies                ; map with counts of each value in coll
       (filter #(= (second %) 2)) ; Keep values that have 2 occurrences
       count                      ; number of unique values with only 2 occurrences
       (= 1)))                    ; true if only one unique val in coll with 2 occurrences
```

Which gives:

```
user=> (only-one-pair? '(2 1 4 4 4))
false
user=> (only-one-pair? '(2 2 4 5 7))
true
user=> (only-one-pair? '(1 2 3 4 5))
false
```

Intermediate steps in the function to get a sense of how it works:

```
user=> (->> '(2 2 4 5 7) frequencies)
{2 2, 4 1, 5 1, 7 1}
user=> (->> '(2 2 4 5 7) frequencies (filter #(= (second %) 2)))
([2 2])
user=> (->> '(2 2 4 5 7) frequencies (filter #(= (second %) 2)) count)
1
```

Per a suggestion, the function could use a more descriptive name and it's also best practice to give predicate functions a ? at the end of it in Clojure. So maybe something like only-one-pair? is better than just check.

Comment: Nice solution, which also works with other collection types. IMHO, it'd be good to give the function a better, less generic, name, which also reflects its predicate nature. Something like `contains-just-one-pair?` or so.

Comment: I agree with that.

Answer (score 3):

[Christian Gonzalez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54014717/625403) is elegant, and great if you are sure you are operating on a small input. However, it is eager: it forces the entire input list even when itcould in principle tell sooner that the result will be false. This is a problem if the list is very large, or if it is a lazy list whose elements are expensive to compute - try it on `(list* 1 1 1 (range 1e9))`! I therefore present below an alternative that short-circuits as soon as it finds a second duplicate:

```
(defn exactly-one-duplicate? [coll]
  (loop [seen #{}
         xs (seq coll)
         seen-dupe false]
    (if-not xs
      seen-dupe
      (let [x (first xs)]
        (if (contains? seen x)
          (and (not seen-dupe)
               (recur seen (next xs) true))
          (recur (conj seen x) (next xs) seen-dupe))))))
```

Naturally it is rather more cumbersome than the carefree approach, but I couldn't see a way to get this short-circuiting behavior without doing everything by hand. I would love to see an improvement that achieves the same result by combining higher-level functions.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your solution would duplicate the (possibly huge) collection in the `seen` set for the case when the result is `true`. In that case, you'd trade speed for memory. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @StefanKamphausen What trade? Every other solution requires at least as much space as this one. How will you find duplicates if you don't remember which items you've seen so far? This one takes *less* space because it doesn't keep accumulating a map once it knows it can stop; it also doesn't store a pointless integer for each unique item in the input.

Comment: you're right. I forgot about `frequencies` duplicating the collection, too.

Comment: I've attempted [a combinatory solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54165135/1562315).

Answer (score 1):

```
(letfn [(check [xs] (->> xs distinct count (= (dec (count xs)))))]
    (clojure.test/are [input output]
        (= (check input) output)
        [1 2 3 4 5] false
        [1 2 1 4 5] true
        [1 2 1 2 1] false))
```

but I like a shorter (but limited to exactly 5 item lists):

```
(check [xs] (->> xs distinct count (= 4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In answer to Alan Malloy's plea, here is a somewhat combinatory solution:

```
(defn check [coll]
  (let [accums (reductions conj #{} coll)]
    (->> (map contains? accums coll)
         (filter identity)
         (= (list true)))))
```

This

- creates a lazy sequence of the accumulating set;
- tests it against each corresponding new element;
- filters for the `true` cases - those where the element is already present;
- tests whether there is exactly one of them.

It is lazy, but does duplicate the business of scanning the given collection. I tried it on Alan Malloy's example:

```
=> (check (list* 1 1 1 (range 1e9)))
false
```

This returns instantly. Extending the range makes no difference:

```
=> (check (list* 1 1 1 (range 1e20)))
false
```

... also returns instantly.

---

Edited to accept Alan Malloy's suggested simplification, which I have had to modify to avoid what appears to be a bug in Clojure 1.10.0.

Comment: Ah, very good. One slight error: you should use `seq` and `next` instead of `first` and `second`, else you risk getting the wrong answer on a collection that contains booleans or nil. edit: no, I see - you're checking a list known to contain only `true`s. In that case, you could replace the `every-pred` entirely with `(= [true])`, couldn't you?

Comment: @amalloy Tried `(= [true])`. It loses laziness. That's a bug, surely. `(= (list true))` works.

Comment: That is a very interesting result. I was surprised to find that `(= (range) [])` returns false immediately, but `(= [] (range))` loops indefinitely. Apparently this has been the case ~forever and I just never noticed.

Comment: @amalloy If the first collection is counted, does it try to count the second, whether counted or not? This is avoidable. Your ticket or mine?

Comment: It's complicated. The problem is in c.l.APersistentVector/doEquiv, which assumes that instances of j.u.List have a fast size() method, even though every clojure collection is a List but not all of them are Counted.

Comment: @amalloy Should the question go to the Google group? the Google dev group? An asymmetric `=` operator, entailing a needless failure to terminate, seems a high price to pay for a questionable performance benefit. I'm assuming the `Counted`ness could be checked.

Comment: If it were me, I'd just file a JIRA ticket. But I don't participate in Clojure dev anymore. If you think you could get useful advice from clojure-dev then that sounds like a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
(defn check [my-list]
  (not (empty? (filter (fn[[k v]] (= v 2)) (frequencies my-list)))))

(check '(2 4 5 7))
(check '(2 2 4 5 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to others using frequencies - just apply twice

```
(-> coll
    frequencies
    vals
    frequencies
    (get 2)
    (= 1))
```

Positive case:

```
(def coll '(2 2 4 5 7))

frequencies=> {2 2, 4 1, 5 1, 7 1}
vals=> (2 1 1 1)
frequencies=> {2 1, 1 3}
(get (frequencies #) 2)=> 1
```

Negative case:

```
(def coll '(2 1 4 4 4))

frequencies=> {2 1, 1 1, 4 3}
vals=> (1 1 3)
frequencies=> {1 2, 3 1}
(get (frequencies #) 2)=> nil
```